# issue With NSTIMER iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nstimer

i wrote like:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:900 target:self selector:@selector(CallGetCounts) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

that means i want to repeat my timer for every 5 mins but my timer is not repeating, not able to find the reason

can any one please tell me the answer.

I wrote this in "`AppDelegate`" -> "`- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`" method.

Comment: i tested with "[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(CallGetCounts) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];" also but at that time my timer is not repeating

Comment: What kind of object is `self`? Is it being released? Does it actually respond to the `CallGetCounts` method? Can we see some of your code?

Comment: i wrote this in "AppDelegate" -> "- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application" method.

Comment: and in "CallGetCounts" i am calling some services to set the badge for application but this method is not calling.

Comment: In background your code is suspended and no timer events you will receive until your application comes to the foreground again.

Comment: You should go for scheduled local notifications to get waken up from background after a given interval. However they will show a popup or a banner to the user that he has to accept first.

Comment: @MrTJ yes that is what exactly happening in my app...how can i achive this

Comment: @MrTJ i don't have any idea about notifications...can  you please provide some examples

Comment: Create a `UILocalNotification` object, set it's fire time, popup text, sound, etc. (see the help for `UILocalNotification` class) and schedule it with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];`. It will call back your AppDelegate's `didReceiveLocalNotification` when it is fired.

Comment: Sidenote: 5 minutes would be a timeInterval of **300**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In background your code is suspended and no timer events you will receive until your application comes to the foreground again.

You should go for scheduled local notifications to get waken up from background after a given interval. However they will show a popup or a banner to the user that he has to accept first.

Here are some steps on how to do it:

```
// When you want to schedule:
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5]; // seconds
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];  
localNotification.alertBody = @"Body text";
localNotification.alertAction = @"Button text";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

// when it's fired it will call your AppDelegate's didReceiveLocalNotification
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)localNotification 
{ 
    // you can handle timer event here and eventually re-schedule your local notification
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally when an app enters the background, it is suspended so it doesn't execute at all.  In particular, NSTimers don't fire.  If you want something to happen in the background, you need to configure your app to run in the background and use one of the approved methods of performing the task you want to do.  running NSTimers is not one of the supported tasks.

I suggest you review the iOS Programming Guide and particularly the [Background Execution and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20) section.

Answer (score 1):

The instance of `UILocalNotification` fires the pop up box(and waken up your app) whenever it triggered as per the time you set, If you really chosen the `UILocalNotification` then [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7429242/1154991) are the good tutorial links discussed in S.O thread. Hope those will help you.