# NSDate always return UTC

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, localtime

I am using `NSDateFormatter` to convert `NSString` into `NSDate` according to local timezone. but it always returns in UTC. I am using this code:

```
NSString *dateString = @"28-12-2015 04:58:10 PM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
// if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
// voila!
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

In console I am getting this:

```
Printing description of dateFromString:
2015-12-28 11:28:10 +0000
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: My dear Sudha, you will never get NSLog in local format, it will always be in GMT. :P

Comment: @AnoopVaidya but in Local Notification, it is not working

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I want UIlocalNotification according to my current time. Can you please help me out

Comment: Sure mam, I posted as an answer.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I have NSString and I want to change in NSDate according to current timezone and want to pass that date as firedate in UILocalNotification

Comment: Can you please post your code for local notification

Comment: This question has nothing to do with date formatting and appears to be a question about local notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the time zone to GMT

```
NSString *dateString = @"28-12-2015 04:58:10 PM";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];    
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

In console I got

```
2015-12-28 16:58:10 +0000
```

Comment: Still in UTC format. I want NSDate in localtime zone

Comment: Can you try giving timezone as [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]. It worked for me. In console I got time correct time in 24 hour format

Comment: Can you show me the code

Comment: But the time you are getting is in GMT not in local time zone. I think the issue is not with date here

Comment: I also got this but local notification is not fired

Comment: The console output what you posted in question is in GMT. When GMT+5:30 is considered it is giving the correct time. Hope you are from India :)

Answer (score 1):

Every time you print `NSDate` either through `NSLog` or print or PO or anyother way it will print in GMT, there is no way to alter `NSDate` to save the date in your desired way.

What you can do it change the format using `NSDateFormatter` and store the date as string and use it.

Comment: How can I pass NSString as a fire date in UILocalNotification

Comment: Pass NSDate itself but set the locale/timezone as well

Comment: @SudhaTiwari: There is timezone method iin UILocalNotifation, did you set it?

Comment: Yes anoop. I wrote   theNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

Comment: But didn't get any notification

Comment: I want to fire notification on 28-12-2015 05:23:10 PM

Comment: May be you are missing some other thing, the issue is not with the NSDate here.

Comment: Please check this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429081/need-any-example-of-uilocalnotifications

Answer (score -1):

```
NSDate* date = nil;
NSDateFormatter*dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
date = [dateformatter dateFromString:time];
NSInteger interval = [[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
date = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval];
```